# Updating product images programmatically

Tags: magento-1.7, product, image, gallery

I have created one custom module where user(customer) can upload and edit his own product through frontend( my account ) dashboard. In this I have used code to edit the image and set it to thumbnail, base, and image for uploaded product. But it was not updating the Image. So Later on I tried to change through admin dashboard. Even after setting up thumbnail, small_image and and image but now it is not upating the product image for any product through admin dashboard(backend).

I have used the code

```
if (!$product->hasSmallImage()) $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) $product->setThumbnail(Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail'));
```

I dont know where should check for the error as it is not showing error on admin dashboard as well. I have checked the database for product_entity table and for gallery and it is showing the image.

Comment: its help me : http://www.onlinecode.org/blog/2016/12/19/magento-update-product-image/

Answer (score 2):

Have you called  $product->save()  method after below code?

```
if (!$product->hasSmallImage())
   $product->setSmallImage($product->getImage());
if (!$product->hasThumbnail()) 
   $product->setThumbnail(Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, array('thumbnail','small_image','image')));
```

**Update::**
set the Small Image, Thumbnail and image.

Comment: Yes, after saving got another issue with this code now unable to update the image through dashboard.. it is not setting up as thumbnail small image and base image .. :(

Comment: I have Update the Code.

Comment: @MagentoBoy are any errors presented? Or does it just refuse to save at all?

Comment: its help me :  http://www.onlinecode.org/blog/2016/12/19/magento-update-product-image/